# Force redraw of view from inside fragment

Tags: android, view, refresh, fragment, invalidation

I have a fragment with an arbitrary number of TextViews that can be added by the user. The problem is that TextViews are added on top of each other as the view is not refreshed. How do I solve this?

I've tried invalidate() / postinvalidate(), but they have no effect. I'm guessing they can't be called from within the fragment.

How should I deal with this?

Comment: call `invalidate()` on the view to refresh

Comment: As I state in my question, I tried that but they had no effect.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate(). show your code. it should work

Comment: @CaptainHindsight Where is your code ? Try to add your `TextView` in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: The code is a mess, I'm moving things around. Really I'm interested in the principle though. So far it seems a view can't be invalidated from within a fragment.